# Clarifications of measure theoretic definition of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, definition

Wikipedia defines a **random variable**:

Let $(\Omega,F,P)$ be a probability space and $(E,S)$ a measurable space. Then an $(E,S)$-valued random variable is a measurable function $X:\Omega \to E$, which means that, for every subset $B \in S$, its pre-image $X^{-1}(B)\in F$ where $X^{-1}(B)= \{\omega: X(\omega)\in B\}$. This definition enables us to measure any subset $B \in S$ in the target space by looking at its pre-image, which by assumption is measurable.

> **Question 1**. Do all $E$-values in $E$ to which the random variable maps have to be included as part of some event in $S$? Since $S$ is a sigma-algebra in measurable space $(E,S)$ it has to include all of $E$, right?
>
> **Question 2**. One of the elements in $S$ will always be $E$ (since $S$ is a sigma-algebra on $E$) and the same goes for $(\Omega,F)$. Does the random variable always map entire $E$ to probability of entire $\Omega$ (i.e. probability of entire $E$ is always 1)?
>
> **Question 3**. Is it possible to have events in $S$ that do not have probability i.e. are not mapped to any event in $F$?

I realise the questions overlap somewhat.

Comment: What are "$$-valued elements in $$"?

Comment: Since the RV maps to , it will take on values in  i.e. the RV is "-valued". So, "-valued elements in " refer to all the possible values of the random variable.

Comment: @cjkilimanjaro That is not a right way of speaking. Yes, in this context rv $X$ takes values in $E$ but the term "E-valued elements in E" is confusing and does not include any reference to the random variable $X$. The elements in $E$ are not equipped with any value, but are values themselves. Further you can speak of the range of $X$ if you want to discern values that can be taken by $X$ from values that cannot be taken by $X$.

Comment: Is it always the case that the range of  includes all elements in , or could there be elements of  which are not in the range of ?

Comment: It is certainly not always the case that the range of $X$ includes all elements in $E$. It is even possible that $X:\Omega\to E$ is a constant function so that the range of $X$ is a singleton (i.e. a set that contains only one element). If you react on a comment of someone then you better start with @ followed by the name, to draw his/her attention.

Comment: @ drhab A RV is defined as a measurable function between two measurable spaces. Doesn't that mean that if  is a constant function so that the range of  is a singleton then  MUST be the set with ONLY the singleton as element. Since the sigma-algebra in the measurable set MUST include entire  and the pre-image of all events in the sigma-algebra must be in  ??

Comment: Try to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting math.

Answer (score 1):

1) This question is unclear because there is no common notion of "$ E$-valued elements of $E$".

Further $E\in S$ because $S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and of course $E$ contains every element of $E$. This is actually a tautology.

2) $X^{-1}(E):=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\in E\}$ and evidently every element of $\Omega$ is sent to $E$. So we conclude that $X^{-1}(E)=\Omega$ and consequently: $$P_X(E)=P(X^{-1}(E))=P(\Omega)=1$$

3) $X$ is not mapping elements of $S$ to events of $F$. It maps elements of $\Omega$ to elements of $E$. Then for every element $B$ of $S$ there is a preimage under $X$ which is a subset of $\Omega$. The measurability of $X$ ensures that all these preimages are elements of $F$ so that they can all be measured by $P$. That opens the door for defining a probability measure $P_X$ on $(E,S)$ by stating that: $$P_X(B):=P(X^{-1}(B))$$

Answer (score 0):

You are getting confused between image and inverse image.

$E$ is certainly in $S$ and the inverse image of $E$ under any map from $\Omega $ to $E$ is always $\Omega$.

For every set $F$ is $S$ certainly $P(X \in F)=P(X^{-1}(F))$ is well defined.

Comment: @ Kabo Murphy Would do you mean by "For every set $F$ is $S$ certainly $P(X \in F)=P(X^{-1}(F))$ is well defined."?